# Accidentally increased package-lock.json lockfileVersion. How to revert?

Tags: npm

Not realizing what I was doing, I committed using npm v7 while my colleague was using npm v6 and I upgraded the lockfileversion to 2.  We decided I should use nvm v6 for now, but is there an appropriate way to use a nvm to revert lockfileversion  back to 1?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `node_modules` directory
2. Remove `package-lock.json` file
3. Install npm 6 with `npm install -g npm@latest-6`
4. Run `npm install`